# Hahn-Banch theorem in Rudin functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, dual-spaces

On page 59, in the first part of the geometric form of Hahn-Banach theorem, it only assumed that $X$ is a topological space and it says

> there exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ and ...

Here $X^*$ is the continuous dual.

But we know when the topological vector space is not locally convex, the continuous dual space might be trivial, $L^p[0,1]$ where $0<p<1$ is such example. How is this possible?

In the second part of the theorem, we have the additional assumption that $X$ is locally convex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The theorem never in any way asserts that a nontrivial element of $X^*$ must exist for arbitrary $X$.  It only asserts that *given* disjoint, nonempty convex sets $A,B\subset X$ with $A$ open, then there exists a $\Lambda\in X^*$ satisfying the stated inequalities.  It's entirely possible that for some $X$, no such sets $A$ and $B$ exist.